# How do I make filter_slider() a single value slider?

Tags: r, crosstalk

Consider this very simple data and code:

```
library(crosstalk)

dat<-data.frame(Year=c(81,82,83,84,85,86,87),
            Sorrow=c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6))

shared_dat<-SharedData$new(dat)

filter_slider("Year","Year",shared_dat,~Year)
```

Using this code, we end up with a slider that allows the user to select a range of values for the "Year" variable.

In walking someone through time, I'd prefer to select a single year value, without a range.

In the documentation for `filter_slider()`, found here: https://rdrr.io/cran/crosstalk/man/filter_slider.html#heading-1, the dragRange description

> "This option is used only if it is a range slider (with two values).
> If TRUE (the default), the range can be dragged. In other words, the
> min and max can be dragged together. If FALSE, the range cannot be
> dragged."

leads me to believe that there IS an option to have the filter NOT use two values.

So far, I have stumbled through the various arguments to the `filter_slider()` function to no avail.  I found the source code here: https://rdrr.io/cran/crosstalk/src/R/controls.R, but I can't locate anything that I'd know to tweak to fix my problem.

I have found that when i click the link to animationOptions, I am brought to the `sliderInput()` function from the `shiny` package.  I noticed that this function allows for specification of a single value, but I need to keep things client-side and haven't figured out how to use this different function in the context of crosstalk.

The warmest I think I've gotten is identifying that within the source code for `filter_slider()`, the `value` argument is set to "range(values)".  When I change this, the graphical slider works as desired, but the data does not appear to be filtering appropriately.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit: Long Example**

Please excuse length there, but I've copied and tweaked code and added a datatable as a test to verify that the data is filtering as expected.  When the handle is on any given value, the goal would be to have the data filtered such that the datatable reflects only data where the Year variable matches that value.

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

library(crosstalk)
```
````

```
dat<-data.frame(Year=c(81,82,83,84,85,86,87),
                Sorrow=c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6))

shared_dat<-SharedData$new(dat)
```

```
###functions with tweak

library(htmltools)

bootstrapGrid <- function() {
  htmlDependency(
    name = "bootstrap-grid",
    version = "3.4.1", # must be updated with tools/updateBootstrapGrid.R
    package = "crosstalk",
    src = "lib/bootstrap",
    stylesheet = "bootstrap-grid.min.css",
    meta = list(viewport = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1")
  )
}

selectizeLib <- function(bootstrap = TRUE) {
  htmlDependency(
    name = "selectize",
    version = "0.12.4",
    package = "crosstalk",
    src = "lib/selectize",
    stylesheet = if (bootstrap) "css/selectize.bootstrap3.css",
    script = "js/selectize.min.js"
  )
}

jqueryLib <- function() {
  htmlDependency(
    name = "jquery",
    version = "3.5.1",
    package = "crosstalk",
    src = "lib/jquery",
    script = "jquery.min.js"
  )
}

# Essentially the same as shiny:::ionRangeSliderDependency()
ionRangeSliderLibs <- function() {
  list(
    jqueryLib(),
    htmlDependency(
      "ionrangeslider-javascript",
      ionRangeSliderVersion,
      package = "crosstalk",
      src = "lib/ionrangeslider",
      script = "js/ion.rangeSlider.min.js",
    ),
    htmlDependency(
      name = "strftime",
      version = "0.9.2",
      package = "crosstalk",
      src = "lib/strftime",
      script = "strftime-min.js"
    ),
    if (is_available("bslib")) {
      bslib::bs_dependency_defer(ionRangeSliderDependencyCSS)
    } else {
      ionRangeSliderDependencyCSS()
    }
  )
}

ionRangeSliderDependencyCSS <- function(theme = NULL) {
  if (!is_bs_theme(theme)) {
    return(htmlDependency(
      "ionrangeslider-css",
      ionRangeSliderVersion,
      package = "crosstalk",
      src = "lib/ionrangeslider",
      stylesheet = "css/ion.rangeSlider.css"
    ))
  }

  bslib::bs_dependency(
    input = list(
      list(accent = "$component-active-bg"),
      sass::sass_file(
        system.file(package = "crosstalk", "lib/ionrangeslider/scss/shiny.scss")
      )
    ),
    theme = theme,
    name = "ionrangeslider-css",
    version = ionRangeSliderVersion,
    cache_key_extra = fastPackageVersion("crosstalk")
  )
}

ionRangeSliderVersion <- "2.3.1"

is_bs_theme <- function(x) {
  is_available("bslib") && bslib::is_bs_theme(x)
}


makeGroupOptions <- function(sharedData, group, allLevels) {
  df <- sharedData$data(
    withSelection = FALSE,
    withFilter = FALSE,
    withKey = TRUE
  )

  if (inherits(group, "formula"))
    group <- lazyeval::f_eval(group, df)

  if (length(group) < 1) {
    stop("Can't form options with zero-length group vector")
  }

  lvls <- if (is.factor(group)) {
    if (allLevels) {
      levels(group)
    } else {
      levels(droplevels(group))
    }
  } else {
    sort(unique(group))
  }
  matches <- match(group, lvls)
  vals <- lapply(1:length(lvls), function(i) {
    df$key_[which(matches == i)]
  })

  lvls_str <- as.character(lvls)

  options <- list(
    items = data.frame(value = lvls_str, label = lvls_str, stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
    map = setNames(vals, lvls_str),
    group = sharedData$groupName()
  )

  options
}

#' Categorical filter controls
#'
#' Creates a select box or list of checkboxes, for filtering a
#' \code{\link{SharedData}} object based on categorical data.
#'
#' @param id An HTML element ID; must be unique within the web page
#' @param label A human-readable label
#' @param sharedData \code{SharedData} object with the data to filter
#' @param group A one-sided formula whose values will populate this select box.
#'   Generally this should be a character or factor column; if not, it will be
#'   coerced to character.
#' @param allLevels If the vector described by \code{group} is factor-based,
#'   should all the levels be displayed as options, or only ones that are
#'   present in the data?
#' @param multiple Can multiple values be selected?
#' @param columns Number of columns the options should be arranged into.
#'
#' @examples
#' ## Only run examples in interactive R sessions
#' if (interactive()) {
#'
#' sd <- SharedData$new(chickwts)
#' filter_select("feedtype", "Feed type", sd, "feed")
#'
#' }
#'
#' @export
filter_select <- function(id, label, sharedData, group, allLevels = FALSE,
  multiple = TRUE) {

  options <- makeGroupOptions(sharedData, group, allLevels)

  htmltools::browsable(htmltools::attachDependencies(
    tags$div(id = id, class = "form-group crosstalk-input-select crosstalk-input",
      tags$label(class = "control-label", `for` = id, label),
      tags$div(
        tags$select(
          multiple = if (multiple) NA else NULL
        ),
        tags$script(type = "application/json",
          `data-for` = id,
          jsonlite::toJSON(options, dataframe = "columns", pretty = TRUE)
        )
      )
    ),
    c(list(jqueryLib(), selectizeLib()), crosstalkLibs())
  ))
}

columnize <- function(columnCount, elements) {
  if (columnCount <= 1 || length(elements) <= 1) {
    return(elements)
  }

  columnSize <- ceiling(length(elements) / columnCount)
  lapply(1:ceiling(length(elements) / columnSize), function(i) {
    tags$div(class = "crosstalk-options-column",
      {
        start <- (i-1) * columnSize + 1
        end <- i * columnSize
        elements[start:end]
      }
    )
  })
}

#' @param inline If \code{TRUE}, render checkbox options horizontally instead of vertically.
#'
#' @rdname filter_select
#' @export
filter_checkbox <- function(id, label, sharedData, group, allLevels = FALSE, inline = FALSE, columns = 1) {
  options <- makeGroupOptions(sharedData, group, allLevels)

  labels <- options$items$label
  values <- options$items$value
  options$items <- NULL # Doesn't need to be serialized for this type of control

  makeCheckbox <- if (inline) inlineCheckbox else blockCheckbox

  htmltools::browsable(htmltools::attachDependencies(
    tags$div(id = id, class = "form-group crosstalk-input-checkboxgroup crosstalk-input",
      tags$label(class = "control-label", `for` = id, label),
      tags$div(class = "crosstalk-options-group",
        columnize(columns,
          mapply(labels, values, FUN = function(label, value) {
            makeCheckbox(id, value, label)
          }, SIMPLIFY = FALSE, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
        )
      ),
      tags$script(type = "application/json",
        `data-for` = id,
        jsonlite::toJSON(options, dataframe = "columns", pretty = TRUE)
      )
    ),
    c(list(jqueryLib()), crosstalkLibs())
  ))
}

blockCheckbox <- function(id, value, label) {
  tags$div(class = "checkbox",
    tags$label(
      tags$input(type = "checkbox", name = id, value = value),
      tags$span(label)
    )
  )
}

inlineCheckbox <- function(id, value, label) {
  tags$label(class = "checkbox-inline",
    tags$input(type = "checkbox", name = id, value = value),
    tags$span(label)
  )
}

#' Range filter control
#'
#' Creates a slider widget that lets users filter observations based on a range
#' of values.
#'
#' @param id An HTML element ID; must be unique within the web page
#' @param label A human-readable label
#' @param sharedData \code{SharedData} object with the data to filter
#' @param column A one-sided formula whose values will be used for this slider.
#'   The column must be of type \code{\link{Date}}, \code{\link{POSIXt}}, or
#'   numeric.
#' @param step Specifies the interval between each selectable value on the
#'   slider (if \code{NULL}, a heuristic is used to determine the step size). If
#'   the values are dates, \code{step} is in days; if the values are times
#'   (POSIXt), \code{step} is in seconds.
#' @param round \code{TRUE} to round all values to the nearest integer;
#'   \code{FALSE} if no rounding is desired; or an integer to round to that
#'   number of decimal places (for example, 1 will round to the nearest 0.1, and
#'   -2 will round to the nearest 100). Any rounding will be applied after
#'   snapping to the nearest step.
#' @param ticks \code{FALSE} to hide tick marks, \code{TRUE} to show them
#'   according to some simple heuristics.
#' @param animate \code{TRUE} to show simple animation controls with default
#'   settings; \code{FALSE} not to; or a custom settings list, such as those
#'   created using \code{\link[shiny]{animationOptions}}.
#' @param width The width of the slider control (see
#'   \code{\link[htmltools]{validateCssUnit}} for valid formats)
#' @param sep Separator between thousands places in numbers.
#' @param pre A prefix string to put in front of the value.
#' @param post A suffix string to put after the value.
#' @param timeFormat Only used if the values are Date or POSIXt objects. A time
#'   format string, to be passed to the Javascript strftime library. See
#'   \url{https://github.com/samsonjs/strftime} for more details. The allowed
#'   format specifications are very similar, but not identical, to those for R's
#'   \code{\link{strftime}} function. For Dates, the default is \code{"\%F"}
#'   (like \code{"2015-07-01"}), and for POSIXt, the default is \code{"\%F \%T"}
#'   (like \code{"2015-07-01 15:32:10"}).
#' @param timezone Only used if the values are POSIXt objects. A string
#'   specifying the time zone offset for the displayed times, in the format
#'   \code{"+HHMM"} or \code{"-HHMM"}. If \code{NULL} (the default), times will
#'   be displayed in the browser's time zone. The value \code{"+0000"} will
#'   result in UTC time.
#' @param dragRange This option is used only if it is a range slider (with two
#'   values). If \code{TRUE} (the default), the range can be dragged. In other
#'   words, the min and max can be dragged together. If \code{FALSE}, the range
#'   cannot be dragged.
#' @param min The leftmost value of the slider. By default, set to the minimal
#'   number in input data.
#' @param max The rightmost value of the slider. By default, set to the maximal
#'   number in input data.
#' @examples
#' ## Only run examples in interactive R sessions
#' if (interactive()) {
#'
#' sd <- SharedData$new(mtcars)
#' filter_slider("mpg", "Miles per gallon", sd, "mpg")
#'
#' }
#' @export
filter_slider <- function(id, label, sharedData, column, step = NULL,
  round = FALSE, ticks = TRUE, animate = FALSE, width = NULL, sep = ",",
  pre = NULL, post = NULL, timeFormat = NULL,
  timezone = NULL, dragRange = TRUE, min = NULL, max = NULL)
{
  # TODO: Check that this works well with factors
  # TODO: Handle empty data frame, NA/NaN/Inf/-Inf values

  if (is.character(column)) {
    column <- lazyeval::f_new(as.symbol(column))
  }

  df <- sharedData$data(withKey = TRUE)
  col <- lazyeval::f_eval(column, df)
  values <- na.omit(col)
  if (is.null(min))
    min <- min(values)
  if (is.null(max))
    max <- max(values)
  value <- range(values[1])

  ord <- order(col)
  options <- list(
    values = col[ord],
    keys = df$key_[ord],
    group = sharedData$groupName()
  )

  # If step is NULL, use heuristic to set the step size.
  findStepSize <- function(min, max, step) {
    if (!is.null(step)) return(step)

    range <- max - min
    # If short range or decimals, use continuous decimal with ~100 points
    if (range < 2 || hasDecimals(min) || hasDecimals(max)) {
      step <- pretty(c(min, max), n = 100)
      step[2] - step[1]
    } else {
      1
    }
  }

  if (inherits(min, "Date")) {
    if (!inherits(max, "Date") || !inherits(value, "Date"))
      stop("`min`, `max`, and `value must all be Date or non-Date objects")
    dataType <- "date"

    if (is.null(timeFormat))
      timeFormat <- "%F"

  } else if (inherits(min, "POSIXt")) {
    if (!inherits(max, "POSIXt") || !inherits(value, "POSIXt"))
      stop("`min`, `max`, and `value must all be POSIXt or non-POSIXt objects")
    dataType <- "datetime"

    if (is.null(timeFormat))
      timeFormat <- "%F %T"

  } else {
    dataType <- "number"
  }

  if (isTRUE(round))
    round <- 0
  else if (!is.numeric(round))
    round <- NULL
  step <- findStepSize(min, max, step)
  # Avoid ugliness from floating point errors, e.g.
  # findStepSize(min(quakes$mag), max(quakes$mag), NULL)
  # was returning 0.01999999999999957 instead of 0.2
  step <- signif(step, 14)

  if (dataType %in% c("date", "datetime")) {
    # For Dates, this conversion uses midnight on that date in UTC
    to_ms <- function(x) 1000 * as.numeric(as.POSIXct(x))

    # Convert values to milliseconds since epoch (this is the value JS uses)
    # Find step size in ms
    step  <- to_ms(max) - to_ms(max - step)
    min   <- to_ms(min)
    max   <- to_ms(max)
    value <- to_ms(value)
  }

  range <- max - min

  # Try to get a sane number of tick marks
  if (ticks) {
    n_steps <- range / step

    # Make sure there are <= 10 steps.
    # n_ticks can be a noninteger, which is good when the range is not an
    # integer multiple of the step size, e.g., min=1, max=10, step=4
    scale_factor <- ceiling(n_steps / 10)
    n_ticks <- n_steps / scale_factor

  } else {
    n_ticks <- NULL
  }

  
  
  
  sliderProps <- dropNulls(list(
    `data-skin` = "shiny",
  # `data-type` = if (length(value) > 1) "double", # crosstalk DEFAULT
    `data-type` = "single", # Force the data type to be single

    `data-min` = formatNoSci(min),
    `data-max` = formatNoSci(max),
    `data-from` = formatNoSci(value[1]),
    `data-to` = if (length(value) > 1) formatNoSci(value[2]),
    `data-step` = formatNoSci(step),
    `data-grid` = ticks,
    `data-grid-num` = n_ticks,
    `data-grid-snap` = FALSE,
    `data-prettify-separator` = sep,
    `data-prefix` = pre,
    `data-postfix` = post,
    `data-keyboard` = TRUE,
    `data-keyboard-step` = step / (max - min) * 100,
    `data-drag-interval` = dragRange,
    `data-round` = round,
    #`data-min-interval`=0,
    #`data-max-interval`=0,
    # The following are ignored by the ion.rangeSlider, but are used by Shiny.
    `data-data-type` = dataType,
    `data-time-format` = timeFormat,
    `data-timezone` = timezone
  ))

  # Replace any TRUE and FALSE with "true" and "false"
  sliderProps <- lapply(sliderProps, function(x) {
    if (identical(x, TRUE)) "true"
    else if (identical(x, FALSE)) "false"
    else x
  })

  sliderTag <- div(
    class = "form-group crosstalk-input",
    class = "crosstalk-input-slider js-range-slider",
    id = id,

    style = if (!is.null(width)) paste0("width: ", validateCssUnit(width), ";"),
    if (!is.null(label)) controlLabel(id, label),
    do.call(tags$input, sliderProps),
    tags$script(type = "application/json",
      `data-for` = id,
      jsonlite::toJSON(options, dataframe = "columns", pretty = TRUE)
    )
  )

  # Add animation buttons
  if (identical(animate, TRUE))
    animate <- shiny::animationOptions()

  if (!is.null(animate) && !identical(animate, FALSE)) {
    if (is.null(animate$playButton))
      animate$playButton <- shiny::icon('play', lib = 'glyphicon')
    if (is.null(animate$pauseButton))
      animate$pauseButton <- shiny::icon('pause', lib = 'glyphicon')

    sliderTag <- tagAppendChild(
      sliderTag,
      tags$div(class='slider-animate-container',
        tags$a(href='#',
          class='slider-animate-button',
          'data-target-id'=id,
          'data-interval'=animate$interval,
          'data-loop'=animate$loop,
          span(class = 'play', animate$playButton),
          span(class = 'pause', animate$pauseButton)
        )
      )
    )
  }

  htmltools::browsable(htmltools::attachDependencies(
    sliderTag,
    c(ionRangeSliderLibs(), crosstalkLibs())
  ))
}

hasDecimals <- function(value) {
  truncatedValue <- round(value)
  return (!identical(value, truncatedValue))
}

#' @rdname filter_slider
#'
#' @param interval The interval, in milliseconds, between each animation step.
#' @param loop \code{TRUE} to automatically restart the animation when it
#'   reaches the end.
#' @param playButton Specifies the appearance of the play button. Valid values
#'   are a one-element character vector (for a simple text label), an HTML tag
#'   or list of tags (using \code{\link{tag}} and friends), or raw HTML (using
#'   \code{\link{HTML}}).
#' @param pauseButton Similar to \code{playButton}, but for the pause button.
#'
#' @export
animation_options <- function(interval=1000,
  loop=FALSE,
  playButton=NULL,
  pauseButton=NULL) {
  list(interval=interval,
    loop=loop,
    playButton=playButton,
    pauseButton=pauseButton)
}

#' Arrange HTML elements or widgets in Bootstrap columns
#'
#' This helper function makes it easy to put HTML elements side by side. It can
#' be called directly from the console but is especially designed to work in an
#' R Markdown document. Warning: This will bring in all of Bootstrap!
#'
#' @param ... \code{htmltools} tag objects, lists, text, HTML widgets, or
#'   NULL. These arguments should be unnamed.
#' @param widths The number of columns that should be assigned to each of the
#'   \code{...} elements (the total number of columns available is always 12).
#'   The width vector will be recycled if there are more \code{...} arguments.
#'   \code{NA} columns will evenly split the remaining columns that are left
#'   after the widths are recycled and non-\code{NA} values are subtracted.
#' @param device The class of device which is targeted by these widths; with
#'   smaller screen sizes the layout will collapse to a one-column,
#'   top-to-bottom display instead. xs: never collapse, sm: collapse below
#'   768px, md: 992px, lg: 1200px.
#'
#' @return A \code{\link[htmltools]{browsable}} HTML element.
#'
#' @examples
#' \donttest{
#' library(htmltools)
#'
#' # If width is unspecified, equal widths will be used
#' bscols(
#'   div(style = css(width="100%", height="400px", background_color="red")),
#'   div(style = css(width="100%", height="400px", background_color="blue"))
#' )
#'
#' # Use NA to absorb remaining width
#' bscols(widths = c(2, NA, NA),
#'   div(style = css(width="100%", height="400px", background_color="red")),
#'   div(style = css(width="100%", height="400px", background_color="blue")),
#'   div(style = css(width="100%", height="400px", background_color="green"))
#' )
#'
#' # Recycling widths
#' bscols(widths = c(2, 4),
#'   div(style = css(width="100%", height="400px", background_color="red")),
#'   div(style = css(width="100%", height="400px", background_color="blue")),
#'   div(style = css(width="100%", height="400px", background_color="red")),
#'   div(style = css(width="100%", height="400px", background_color="blue"))
#' )
#' }
#' @export
bscols <- function(..., widths = NA, device = c("xs", "sm", "md", "lg")) {
  device <- match.arg(device)

  if (length(list(...)) == 0) {
    widths = c()
  } else {
    if (length(widths) > length(list(...))) {
      warning("Too many widths provided to bscols; truncating")
    }
    widths <- rep_len(widths, length(list(...)))

    if (any(is.na(widths))) {
      remaining <- 12 - sum(widths, na.rm = TRUE)
      stretch_cols <- length(which(is.na(widths)))
      stretch_width <- max(1, floor(remaining / stretch_cols))
      widths[is.na(widths)] <- stretch_width
    }

    if (sum(widths) > 12) {
      warning("Sum of bscol width units is greater than 12")
    }
  }

  ui <- tags$div(class = "container-fluid crosstalk-bscols",
    # Counteract knitr pre/code output blocks
    tags$div(class = "row",
      unname(mapply(list(...), widths, FUN = function(el, width) {
        div(class = sprintf("col-%s-%s", device, width),
          el
        )
      }, SIMPLIFY = FALSE))
    )
  )

  browsable(htmltools::attachDependencies(ui, list(jqueryLib(), bootstrapGrid())))
}

controlLabel <- function(controlName, label) {
  if (is.null(label)) {
    NULL
  } else {
    tags$label(class = "control-label", `for` = controlName, label)
  }
}

# Given a vector or list, drop all the NULL items in it
dropNulls <- function(x) {
  x[!vapply(x, is.null, FUN.VALUE=logical(1))]
}

# Format a number without sci notation, and keep as many digits as possible (do
# we really need to go beyond 15 digits?)
formatNoSci <- function(x) {
  if (is.null(x)) return(NULL)
  format(x, scientific = FALSE, digits = 15)
}


is_available <- function(package, version = NULL) {
  installed <- nzchar(system.file(package = package))
  if (is.null(version)) {
    return(installed)
  }
  installed && isTRUE(fastPackageVersion(package) >= version)
}
```

```
filter_slider("Year","Year",shared_dat,~Year)
```

```
library(DT)
datatable(shared_dat)
```

Answer (score 1):

The slider is based on range.sliderJS. API Ref [HERE](http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/api.html).

A bit of an arduous solution but what you need to do is update `filter_slider`. Specifically the `data-type` attribute inside `dropNulls()`. By default it is "double" which is why you get a range slider. To make it a single point update it to "single". Or create a new argument for it.

Unfortunately, since crosstalk does not export most of these internal functions [HERE](https://github.com/rstudio/crosstalk/blob/main/R/controls.R), to my knowledge you pretty much need to source the script I have linked.

```
filter_slider2 = function (...) 
{ ...
  sliderProps <- dropNulls(list(
    `data-skin` = "shiny",

   #`data-type` = if (length(value) > 1) "double", # crosstalk DEFAULT
    `data-type` = "single", # Force the data type to be single

    `data-min` = formatNoSci(min),
    `data-max` = formatNoSci(max),
    `data-from` = formatNoSci(value[1]),
    `data-to` = if (length(value) > 1) formatNoSci(value[2]),
    `data-step` = formatNoSci(step),
    `data-grid` = ticks,
    `data-grid-num` = n_ticks,
    `data-grid-snap` = FALSE,
    `data-prettify-separator` = sep,
    `data-prefix` = pre,
    `data-postfix` = post,
    `data-keyboard` = TRUE,
    `data-keyboard-step` = step / (max - min) * 100,
    `data-drag-interval` = dragRange,
    `data-round` = round,
    # The following are ignored by the ion.rangeSlider, but are used by Shiny.
    `data-data-type` = dataType,
    `data-time-format` = timeFormat,
    `data-timezone` = timezone
  ))
```

Once that script is sourced or by loading those functions directly in your environment. It should work after making that 1 liner change.

[image]

Comment: this gets the slider to have a single handle, but doesn't seem to filter the data.  I've updated the example in the question above.  Ideally, with the handle on 83, the goal result would be a table filtered to only year=83, for example.

Comment: @Pake - I see what you mean, I've done some more digging but I think this may require some JS work and I have a limited working knowledge of JS.  When setting data-type = "single". I get the following error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance` But haven't been able to locate where it's caused.